# Spring boot, custom auth handler and Angular 5

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have next problem with my rest application.
I have my backend with an custom auth handler

```
public class AutorizacionFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Autowired
UsuariosService usuarioService;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String dominio = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else if (dominio.startsWith("/api/login") || dominio.startsWith("/api/usuarios")) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        String token = request.getHeader ("Authorization");

        if (token == null || !usuarioService.validarSesion(token)) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "your message goes here");
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

In my web page made witn Angular 5, I have an interceptor for catch the 401 status code

```
 @Injectable()
export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(
req: HttpRequest<any>,
next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
if (!req.headers.has("Content-Type")) {
  req = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  });
}

req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set("Accept", "application/json") });
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
return next.handle(req).do(
  (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      console.log("Autorizacion OK!");
      console.log("Code: " + event.status);
    }
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
      console.log("An error occurred:", err.error.message);
    } else {
      console.log(
        `Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.message}`
      );
    }
  }
);}}
```

When the toker expire the interceptor cant parse the answer and give me this error

> Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

I have a lot of reading about the problem of the httpClient with empty responses, but I cant understand how to fixed/find a way around.

Can anyone give a hand to understand this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide an complete example to produce this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is it an CORS issue?

Comment: No CORS it isnt. if the token is valid , the server respond 200 and works perfectly.

Comment: Have you try to check request & response via Chrome developer tool?

Comment: This error is usually because the answer from the server is not returning the headers so the angular interceptor cant parse it.

Look into the network tab of your browser and in the response from the server you should see Access-Control-Allow-Origin which may not be added in response that arent 20X or 30X

Comment: Yes. The issue is know in angular 5. The issue occurs when the server respond from de filter

Comment: it's not an angular 5 problem, the problem is your server is answering back with invalid response.From your code I assume you are a using spring-security and if so you dont need to do  send error on token being null because spring security will throw an aunthentication error anyway since you are not setting the spring security anthentication to anything in the filter so route with .authenticated() will fail anyway.

Comment: No, I m not using spring security. I ll force the CORS header I think that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Asura answer, I set up the response headers and solve the problem.
This is the code.

```
if (token == null || !usuarioService.validarSesion(token)) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD");
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

            return;
        }
```